# How to reduce the number of tracking records when saving on keystroke?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paper-trail-gem

When saving changes to a model in rails, two popular gems to track changes are [paper_trail](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail) and [audited](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited). These gems create records that contain versioning information every time the model is updated.

How can I reduce the number of records created when saving user input as they type?

For example:

1. User start filling out an input for the title of a model
2. User starts typing "App" then a few second later "le"
3. The database now contains two versioning records "App" and "le"

Note: Putting a delay on the user interface (say 250ms before saving) will reduce the number of records, but we will still have a bunch of updates that are really just one.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to do two things -- automatically save the users changes as they go AND create a coherent changeset when they actually decide to commit the record.  This more easily done using two models. Have the user's in progress changes saved to a draft model that does not use auditing. Then when the user commits, update the for real model (with auditing) using the data from the draft model. This will capture the complete intended set of changes from the last saved version of the real model as a single update.

Comment: @dbugger great idea of a draft model, why not put that in an answer?

Comment: Only snag with the draft model is, it may not be known when the user has completed  her changes.

Comment: Or you add a boolean `changing`  to the entries with paper_trail connection.
Then you can add a a condition to the paper_trail init `unless: proc(&:changing)`
when you comit the last changes to can set the value to false first and ignore `changing` at the init.

Comment: You do need some affirmative indication that they are done done and not kinda done.

Comment: Could be like a 1min timeout in the worst case.

Comment: If you want to remain saving user input as the user types, theres no way to know when the input is done. If theres no way to submit information on demand and avoid on user type, then I would suggest to create a service that runs before every audit log and takes the old and new values and assess if this is a final change/log, you can add a new attribute to identify that the audit is final or even delete previous logs depending on your match.

Comment: @GerardoS that's most likely what i'll do.

Comment: When you save user input (and therefore the record) while they type, when do you actually create a new version? Not after each key, sure? But what about every 10? Or only once per hour? What if the user fixes only one typo? I guess then you want to record it as a new version?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution would be to [skip versioning](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#per-http-request) based on conditions (column, last_updated_at, etc). Then wrap the controller action with the following block.

```
PaperTrail.request(enabled: false) do
  # no versions created
end
```

**Solution**

Use different endpoints for the keystroke requests and form submission.

**Keystroke Endpoint**

Used only by keystroke requests and is wrapped with the code above to `skip_versioning`.

**Form submission endpoint**

Used only when the form is submitted.

Comment: Good idea, after skipping creating a version, what would you do after that?

Comment: @JustinTanner I updated my answer, please have a look.

Comment: Thanks for being the only one to answer, sorry I forgot to award the bounty, my bad.